# Sorting tableview cells by creation (swift)

Tags: swift, core-data, tableview, nssortdescriptor

I would like to sort `tableview` cells, which are loading core data items, by the date/time that the items were created. I've tried to create a `timeStamp` which is stored as an attribute, and then plug it into my sort descriptor to sort by that time stamp which is an `NSDate`. Like this:

```
//save timeStamp to core data
newLog.timeStamp = NSDate()

//retrieve that timeStamp in my tableviewcontroller
var timeStamp = data.valueForKey("timeStamp") as NSDate

//sort by the timeStamp in order to list the most recent items on top of tableview

let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)
let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
```

The `tableview` items are not being sorted in any sensible way from what I can tell. It's as if the sort descriptor isn't being recognized. Again, the point is to get the most recent items to show in order at the top of the list.

Comment: Can you describe what is happening now that is a problem? What isn't working about your current attempt?

Comment: Yes, it seems like the tableview isn't even recognizing the sort descriptor because the items in it are pretty much completely randomized.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sort method of the Array;

```
yourArray.sort({$0.date.timeIntervalSinceNow < $1.date.timeIntervalSinceNow})
```

then `tableView.reloadData()` if you need to reload the tableView. If this is done in `viewDidLoad()`, this is not needed